# JAX RPC Client in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jax-rpc

I have to implement JAX RPC 1.1 client in C#. I have searched but haven't found anything satisfying,except http://www.yaldex.com/java_tutorial_2/Fly0090.html. Please provide some more helpful resources on the same. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the tutorial you mentioned? It seems to have all of the necessary information to do what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JAX RPC` is the the old (and obsolete) java spec for web services.
It has been replaced -long ago- with [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)

In any case if you have an existing JAX-RPC implementation you are trying to reach via C# (BTW I don't know C#) you should be able to, IMO, by the same way you call a web service.
The only "caveat" I can imagine you should look into, is if the service is not doc/literal but the obsolete rpc style.